# Multiple validation rules for a single binding

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

Can multiple validation rules be used on a single binding?
I'm trying to validate `TextBox` using XAML only, and `BindingGroup`doesn't seem to be working.

Here's my XAML:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Title" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    </TextBox.Text>
    <TextBox.BindingGroup>
        <BindingGroup NotifyOnValidationError="True">
            <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
                <rule:CantBeEmpty ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                <rule:CantBeMoreThanXCharacters
                    CharacterLimit="30"
                    ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
            <BindingGroup.ValidationRules/>
        </BindingGroup>
    </TextBox.BindingGroup>
</TextBox>
```

Where the `rule` namespace references `xmlns:rule="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views.ValidationRules"`
These rules follow the standard syntax:

```
public class CantBeEmpty : ValidationRule {
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try to add the validation rules to the binding?:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Title" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <rule:CantBeEmpty ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                <rule:CantBeMoreThanXCharacters CharacterLimit="30" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. My question stemed from an misunderstanding of what a `BindingGroup` does. From MSDN: 

_A BindingGroup creates a relationship between multiple bindings, which can be validated and updated together._ In this case a `BindingGroup` isn't really necessary since only one field needs to be validated. A `BindingGroup` would have been useful multiple fields needed to be validated together — an adress with Zip Code and State, two password fields, etc.